# How to add image as in circular frame in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app i want show image of the caller in circular frame. How to change image view from rectangular frame to a circular one. It should also fit the caller image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `corner radius` property like,

```
 self.imageViewProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 26.5; 
 self.imageViewProfile.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Corner radius should be `half of the height and width of imageview` & `height and width` should be equal of imageview `(i.e. height = width)`.

By this setup you will able to get **rounded imageView**.

and `maskToBounds` set your image as per shape of rounded `imageView`

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Image should be equal height and equal width than you can create circular image.

```
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
yourImageView.layer.clipToBounds = true;
```

I think it would be help full for you.If you have any issue plz let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it works for you

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height /2;
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```